I cannot find work in a folder when assigning it in classroom
I have a folder in drive with all the work in it.  I had spent several hours organizing it. When I go to assign something on Google Classroom, and try to attach work through the drive folder,  the work isn't in the folder.  It is in Drive though.  It was working last week.  Can you help explain what happened?
I have tried making copies, clearing cache, re-downloading work.

Did you use a personal account to share with a work/school account? Maybe you need to re-upload?

No, didn't use a personal account.

It should work like in this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IE67DCqGzs  I know you said it isnt showing up when you try to attach from the drive, maybe you were trying the same thing as in the video. If it isnt showing up there then I would think its something strange with permissions set on your google work/school account by your IT. Maybe try to share the folder with your own personal account then use google classroom on your personal account
